# How to make the + operator work while adding two Points to each other?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, operators, point

Is there any way to get the `+` operator  to work for the Point object?

Take, for example, this tiny snippet:

```
this.cm1.Show((MouseEventArgs)e.Location+this.i_rendered.Location);
```

You see, I try to add two points to eachother. It just does not work (which was expected). I'd love to get this working.

Any ideas?

Comment: What `Point` object are you talking about? Exactly? In what namespace? Is it your own type? What do you expect the result of addition to be?

Comment: Have you tried this.cm1.Show(((MouseEventArgs)e).Location+this.i_rendered.Location);

Comment: @Oded -> System.Drawing.Point

Comment: @Blablablaster Does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not going to happen the way you expect. The only overload that the `Point` structure provides for the `+` (addition) operator is [one that translates the coordinates of the `Point` by a `Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.op_addition.aspx).

There's no way to add two `Point` structures together, and I'm not even sure what that would mean.

Don't waste too much time figuring it out, either, considering that [you cannot write extension methods that overload operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172658/operator-overloading-with-c-sharp-extension-methods).

Fortunately, in a compiled language, there's no penalty for splitting up code into multiple lines. So you can re-write your code as follows:

```
Point newLocation = new Point(e.Location.X + this.i_rendered.Location.X,
                              e.Location.Y + this.i_rendered.Location.Y);
this.cm1.Show(newLocation);
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`Offset` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142187), but I'm not convinced that enhances readability.

Comment: Awww sad that it's not really possible. I guess I'll go that way then, it's at least best readable. - Thanks :).

Comment: Check my answer. Maybe you just need to cast the second addend to `Size`?

Answer (score 10):

I read the documentation for `System.Drawing.Point` (linked in Cody Gray's answer), and it has an instance method `Offset`. That method mutates the current `Point` (the designers chose to make `Point` a mutable struct!).

So here's an example:

```
var p1 = new Point(10, 20);
var p2 = new Point(6, 7);
p1.Offset(p2); // will change p1 into the sum!
```

In the same doc I also see an explicit conversion from `Point` to `Size`. Therefore, try this:

```
var p1 = new Point(10, 20);
var p2 = new Point(6, 7);
Point pTotal = p1 + (Size)p2; // your solution?
```

Comment: The second snippet gets somewhat close, yes, however, it looks terribly confusing. I think Cody Gray's answer is easiest and the clearest solution to apply in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and cleanest) solution is to just cast i_rendered.Location to a **Size**

```
Point newLocation = (e.Location + (Size)this.i_rendered.Location);
```

I don't see how or why anything needs to be split into convoluted X and Y components, when a simple cast does the job in the way the OP was asking for.