# System.Drawing.Point operator error

Tags: c#, location, operators, picturebox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make the + operator work while adding two Points to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663499/how-to-make-the-operator-work-while-adding-two-points-to-each-other)

my code

```
position.Location = (e.Location + pic1.Location) - bild_posi.Location;
```

error smth like:

```
the operator "+" isnt compatible with "System.Drawing.Point + System.Drawing.Point"
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: it is because of the points coordinates. You must sum (e.Location.X + pi1.Location.X) and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It Depends on how you want to add points together

You could write a method called AddPoints and one called SubtractPoints such as

```
private Point AddPoints(Point A, Point B)
{
    return new Point(A.X + B.X, A.Y + B.Y);
}

private Point SubtractPoints(Point A, Point B)
{
    return new Point(A.X - B.X, A.Y - B.Y);
}
```

and then use it like

```
position.Location = SubtractPoints(AddPoints(e.Location,pic1.Location),bild_posi.Location);
```

Comment: +1 for using the methods. Reusable and cleaner than my solution

Answer (score 1):

The [`System.Drawing.Point` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx) does not define an overload of the addition operator that takes two `Point` objects as parameters.

There is an addition operator that accepts a `Point` object and a `Size` object, and then adds the pair of numbers contained in the `Size` object to the values of the `Point` object. The documentation for that function is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.op_addition.aspx).

You can use that version by converting your second `Point` object to a `Size` object. This is pretty easy, since the `Size` structure provides an [explicit conversion operator for `Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.op_explicit.aspx), so all you have to do is cast your second `Point` object to a `Size` object:

```
position.Location = (e.Location + (Size)pic1.Location) - (Size)bild_posi.Location;
```

Note that I had to do the same thing for the third `Point` object, since the subtraction operator is implemented the same way as the addition operator.

Unfortunately, you cannot overload existing operators in C#, but you could create a regular old function that contains the logic internally, and then call that instead of using an operator. You could even make this an extension method of the `Point` class.

**Edit:** [Nuts, it turns out I've answered this one already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663499/how-to-make-the-operator-work-while-adding-two-points-to-each-other/10663526#10663526).

Answer (score 0):

Think of a point as an x/y coordinate on a graph. Unfortunately, you can't just add PointA and PointB to get PointC on the graph.

You need to calculate the x and y coordinates separately to achieve what you are going for.

With that said, try the following

```
var pointA = new Point(e.Location.X + pic1.Location.X, e.Location.Y + pic1.Location.Y);
var pointB = new Point(pointA.Location.X - bild_posi.Location.X, pointA.Location.Y - bild_posi.Location.Y);
position.Location = pointB;
```